# How to write N choose K problem by adding a requirement on the number of groups?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to come up with a formula to evaluate the number of possible combinations. I think the best way to explain my problem is by using an example. If we have 4 numbers $1,2,3,4$ and we want to combine them into 2  equal size groups (order does not matter), we have 3 possible combinations, as given below:
$$12 \quad 34 $$
$$13 \quad 24 $$
$$14 \quad 23 $$
Another example is if we have the same numbers but we want to find all the combinations when we split them into 3 equal groups. In this case equal is not possible, so we allow maximum of $\pm1$ difference between group size. We have 6 combinations which are:
$$12 \quad 3 \quad 4 $$
$$13 \quad 2 \quad 4 $$
$$14 \quad 2 \quad 3 $$
$$23 \quad 1 \quad 4 $$
$$24 \quad 1 \quad 3 $$
$$34 \quad 1 \quad 2 $$

Any idea for an analytical formula on how to express and solve the problem above?

Comment: This is not clear.  If you have $n$ people and you want to split into $k$ groups, do you care what "shape" those $k$ groups take or not?  Look at multinomial coefficients.  Consider how many times you overcount a scenario using multinomial coefficients because you want groups of the same size to be indistinguishable from one another.  $\binom{4}{2,1,1}/2 = 6$

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just added the requirement about that. I am trying to have groups of equal size, but if not possible we can allow for $\pm 1$ difference. I see you solution with multinomial coefficients. Why do you divide by 2 at the end?

Comment: "*Why did I divide by $2$ at the end?*"  "*Consider how many times you overcount a scenario...because you want groups of the same size to be indistinguishable from one another*"  We want to "forget" which group size 1 was which, there are $2$ ways to have labeled them and so we overcounted by a factor of $2$ when we used the multinomial coefficient, so to "forget" we divide by the amount we had counted each... in this case divide by $2$

Comment: "*I am trying to have groups of (approximately) equal size*"  I'll let you work out how to decide how many of size $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ there are and how many of size $\lceil \frac{n}{k}\rceil$ there are... letting there be $s$ "smaller" groups and $\ell$ "larger" groups of size $a$ and $b$ respectively, you'll have $\binom{n}{a,a,\dots,a,b,b,\dots,b} \cdot\frac{1}{s!\ell!}= \frac{n!}{(a!)^s(b!)^\ell s!\ell!}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a lot, that's amazing. If you wish please add this comment as an answer, so I could accept and close the problem.